# Total curvature of a conjugate minimal surface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let $s: S \to \Bbb R^3$ be an immersed minimal surface with finite total curvature and a *proper annular end* (possibly with other types of ends).

What is exactly meant by a proper annular end? It is an embedded topological end of $S$ which is homeomorphic to an annulus, and is not a flat end.

Is it true that the conjugate surface of $S$ will have infinite total curvature?

---

Easy example, which motivates this question, is the helicoid conjugate to the usual catenoid.

If a surface is complete, has all ends embedded, and finite total curvature ($*$), then Shoen's classification tells us that every end is conformally equivalent to a nbhd of a puncture on $\Bbb{CP}^1$. Combined with Osserman theorem, this tells us that "proper annular" is equivalent to "catenoidal" (i. e. it is asymptotic up to second order in Gauss coordinates to a usual catenoid).

So one can ask the question in this restricted setting. This looks like a difficult calculation, but probably there's a way to see explicitly why total curvature of conjugate surface is infinite in case ($*$).